# How to add functions only for test in testthat for R?

Tags: r, testthat

In my package, I would like to add a few functions which are only used for test to check whether a test database can be connected. For example for file `tests/testthat.R`

```
library(testthat)
library(mypackage)
is_test_db <- function() {
    x <- try({
        con <- db_connect()
        on.exit(db_disconnect(con), add = TRUE)
    })
    if (inherits(x, "try-error")) {
        return(FALSE)
    }
    return(TRUE)
}
test_check("mypackage")
```

However, the function `is_test_db` cannot be found in all tests files. How could I define a new function only for all tests?

Comment: Put them in a source file in `tests/testthat/helper.R`

Comment: FYI, they are referenced in [`vignette("special-files")`](https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/special-files.html)